# ColdFusion form: how to refer to a selection from a binding?

Tags: forms, binding, coldfusion

I am not sure if I am thinking about this correctly. I am still new to ColdFusion. I am creating a form which uses binding for the user to select a category and then a specific service. The code for the binding works great. The problem is that now I need to pull some additional information from the service to refer to another field. For example, if the service selected has a "Y" under additional info needed. A field will show that additional information is needed (this field is not changeable)

Originally I thought I could do something like regenerate the same query I did to pull the list of services and just refer to the service type that is selected. Yet I keep getting an error that the field is not defined. Here is the code that I am trying to make it work.

UPDATED: I got it to work I changed the code below the only problem is that I can not get the "Y" to display I get [object Object] instead. Any advice on how to display the text with use of cfinput?

CFC:

```
 <!--- Get array of Catagory Description types --->
 <cffunction name="cat_description" access="remote" returnType="array">

 <!--- Define variables --->
 <cfset var data="">
 <cfset var result=ArrayNew(2)>
 <cfset var i=0>

 <!--- Get data --->
 <cfquery name="getServiceCat" datasource="Some Database">
    select distinct 2 AS SortBy, CATG_NAME
    from some table
    UNION
    select 1 AS SortBy, '' AS CATG_NAME
    from Some table
    order by SortBy
 </cfquery>

 <!--- Convert results to array---> 
 <cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#getServiceCat.recordcount#">
    <cfset result[i][1]=getServiceCat.CATG_NAME[i]>
    <cfset result[i][2]=getServiceCat.CATG_NAME[i]>
 </cfloop>

 <!--- And return it --->
 <cfreturn result>
 </cffunction>

  <!--- Get Service Type by Cat description type --->
  <cffunction name="getServiceType2" access="remote" returnType="array">
  <cfargument name="CATG_NAME" type="string" required="true">

  <cfset var data="">
  <cfset var result=ArrayNew(2)>
  <cfset var i=0>

  <cfquery name="getServiceType2" datasource="Some Database">
    select 1 AS SortBy,  '' AS SRTY_BNR, '' AS SRTY_NAME
    from Some table
    UNION
    select distinct 2 AS SortBy, SRTY_NBR, SRTY_NAME
    from Some Table
    where CATG_NAME = <cfqueryparam value="#ARGUMENTS.CATG_NAME#"   
    cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"> 
    order by SortBy
   </cfquery>

   <cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#getServiceType2.recordcount#">
      <cfset result[i][1]=getServiceType2.SRTY_NAME[i]>
      <cfset result[i][2]=getServiceType2.SRTY_NAME[i]>
   </cfloop>

   <cfreturn result>
   </cffunction>

   <!---Updated below table into CFC to pull information depending on what is pulled   
   from category and service type--->
   <cffunction name="getLR" access="remote" returnType="query">
   <cfargument name="SRTY_NAME" type="string" required="true">

   <cfset var data="">

    <!---Query to get "Y"--->
    <cfquery name="lr_required" datasource="Some Datebase">
  select distinct LAB_REL_NTFN_FLAG 
  from some table
  where SRTY_NAME = <cfqueryparam value="#ARGUMENTS.SRTY_NAME#"  
       cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"> 
</cfquery>

     <cfreturn lr_required>
     </cffunction>
```

Here is the code within the form:

```
<TR id="serv_ty" style="display: inline;">
    <td align="left" nowrap><label>Service Type:</label></td>
    <td>Select Category:
    <cfselect name="catdesc"
    bind="cfc:servicetype2.cat_description()"
    bindonload="true"/><br />
    </td>
</TR>
<tr id="serv_ty2" style="display: inline;">
    <td></td>
    <td>Select Service:
    <cfselect name="service_type"
    bind="cfc:servicetype2.getServiceType2({catdesc})"
    bindonload="false"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

This is the form code to use the bind which works but will not display the DATA:

```
 <tr id="lr_verify" style="display: inline;">
 <td></td>
 <td>Additional Info Reuired:
 <cfinput 
 name="lr_needed"
 bind="cfc:servicetype2.getLR({service_type})"
 bindonload="no"
 disabled="disabled"
 display="LAB_REL_NTFN_FLAG"/></td>
 </tr>
```

Any advice on how to get it to display or if I should use a different CF statement with the bind to get the correct display. Thanks in advnace for your help on this.

Comment: You are trying to do a linked dropdown box, select one, then the second box populates with the related options?

Comment: Couple of points not related to your question.  First, query names are also variables so you should var them in your function.  Second, try to pass numeric arguments if possible.  Related to your problem, the query you added to your form page depends on the form being submitted.  You probably want to move it to your cfc.

Comment: *I get [object Object] instead* Your function returns a `query` object, but `cfinput` expects a simple `string`. Side note, you could greatly simplify your first two functions by returning a query object instead of an array (supported in CF8.0.1+ ). See example at [the bottom of this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14530219/104223)

Comment: Thanks Leigh that is exactly what I need after changing it to send a string it worked Thanks you so much.