# Triple Chained/Related Selects ColdFusion 9

Tags: html, ajax, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfc

Using a AJAX Based Triple Chained/Related Selects in Cold Fusion

I am getting Error Invoking CFC : Internal Server Error Adding cfdebug tag doesn't help

The Triple Chained/Related Select works fine, but generates the error. How can I make stop it from happening. I believe my CFC is coded correctly

Any help will be appreciated

Already Tried bindonload=false for Second Select Does not help Also Tried bindonload=false for First Select Options dont load

Here is my code

CFC:

```
<!--- Get array of media types --->
<cffunction name="getDevice" access="remote" returnType="array">
<!--- Define variables --->
<cfset var data="">
<cfset var result=ArrayNew(2)>
<cfset var i=0> 

<!--- Get data --->
<cfquery name="data" datasource="#dsn#">
SELECT device_id, device_list
FROM pa_device
ORDER BY device_list
</cfquery>

<!--- Convert results to array --->
<cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#data.RecordCount#">
    <cfset result[i][1]=data.device_id[i]>
    <cfset result[i][2]=data.device_list[i]>
</cfloop>

<!--- And return it --->
 <cfreturn result>
 </cffunction>

<!--- Get art by media type --->
<cffunction name="getProblem" access="remote" returnType="array">
<cfargument name="device_id" type="numeric" required="true">

<!--- Define variables --->
<cfset var data="">
<cfset var result=ArrayNew(2)>
<cfset var i=0>

<!--- Get data --->
<cfquery name="data" datasource="#dsn#">
SELECT problem_id, problem_list
FROM pa_problem
WHERE device_id = #ARGUMENTS.device_id#
ORDER BY problem_list
</cfquery>

<!--- Convert results to array --->
<cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#data.RecordCount#">
    <cfset result[i][1]=data.problem_id[i]>
    <cfset result[i][2]=data.problem_list[i]>
</cfloop>

<!--- And return it --->
<cfreturn result>
</cffunction>
<!--- Get art by media type --->
<cffunction name="getdescription" access="remote" returnType="array">
<cfargument name="device_id" type="numeric" required="true">
<cfargument name="problem_id" type="numeric" required="true">

<!--- Define variables --->
<cfset var data="">
<cfset var result=ArrayNew(2)>
<cfset var i=0>

<!--- Get data --->
<cfquery name="data" datasource="#dsn#">
SELECT description_id, description_list, device_id
FROM pa_description
WHERE device_id = #ARGUMENTS.device_id# and problem_id =#arguments.problem_id#
        ORDER BY description_list
</cfquery>

<!--- Convert results to array --->
<cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#data.RecordCount#">
    <cfset result[i][1]=data.description_id[i]>
    <cfset result[i][2]=data.description_list[i]>
</cfloop>

<!--- And return it --->
<cfreturn result>
</cffunction>
```

CFM

```
 <cfform>

<table>
<tr>
<td>Select Device Type:</td>
<td><cfselect name="device"
        bind="cfc:art.getDevice()"
        bindonload="true" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Select Problem Type:</td>
<td><cfselect name="problem"
        bind="cfc:art.getProblem({device})" 
        bindonload="false" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
<td>Select Description Type:</td>
<td><cfselect name="description"
        bind="cfc:art.getdescription({device},{problem})" 
        bindonload="false"/></td>
 </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Did you ask this question before? Regarding the error 1) You need to test the functions *without* ajax first 2) I suspect the error is with `getProblem` and `getDescription`. Both will throw an error if passed an empty string, which could happen with binds. (See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527652/pull-down-with-binding-and-ajax/14530219#14530219) for some tips.) 3) Check the CF logs for more details about the error